# Compiler warning on unused exception...need to improve structure?

Tags: c#, exception-handling, exception

Consider the below:

```
public int DoSomethingComplicated(ComplicatedObject input)
{
    try {
        return input.Analyse();
    }
    catch(CustomExceptionOne ex1)
    {
         throw;
    }
    catch(CustomExceptionTwo ex2)
    {
         Log(ex2.Message);
         return -1;
    }
}
```

Obviously I have abstracted quite a bit for the example, but the idea is that the try block performs a task which can cause one of two types of runtime exception.

In the event that the exception type is `CustomExceptionOne`, I want to simply throw the exception. For `CustomExceptionTwo` on the other hand, I want to log the issue but return -1.

I do not have access to the `input.Analyse()` method in order to change it.

This all looks fine to me, and works fine, but I get a compiler warning because `ex1` is technically never used. I don't really want to throw the entire `ex1` exception, so I am wondering how I can get this warning to go away.

I can think of a couple of hacky ways like `Console.WriteLine(ex1.Message)` or something but that isn't a route I particularly want to go down.

Comment: You should consider logging the entire exception not just the message. Otherwise you throw away the stacktrace and it might be hard to find where it came from.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can refactor your code the following way:

```
public int DoSomethingComplicated(ComplicatedObject input)
{
    try 
    {
        return input.Analyse();
    }
    catch(CustomExceptionTwo ex2)
    {
         Log(ex2.Message);
         return -1;
    }
}
```

`throw;` re-throws the same exception, so there is no point in such catch block.

Alternatively, you can use `catch(CustomExceptionOne)` syntax.